# How to read opc-ua variable in java with hurence

Tags: java, opc-ua

I'm try to read a variable from a OPC-UA server. I’m using com.hurence.opc library. My code is

```
    OpcUaConnectionProfile connectionProfile = new OpcUaConnectionProfile()
            .withConnectionUri(URI.create("opc.tcp://localhost:62541/Quickstarts/ReferenceServer"))
            .withClientIdUri("imp:ladisa").withClientName("GestionaleLadisa")
            .withSocketTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(15));

    // Create an instance of a ua operations
    OpcUaOperations opcUaOperations = new OpcUaTemplate();
    // connect using our profile
    opcUaOperations.connect(connectionProfile).doOnError(throwable -> System.out.println(throwable.getMessage()))
            .ignoreElement().blockingAwait();

    
      OpcUaSessionProfile sessionProfile = new OpcUaSessionProfile()
                //the publication window
                .withPublicationInterval(Duration.ofMillis(100));
      
      
      
        try (OpcSession session = opcUaOperations.createSession(sessionProfile).blockingGet()) {
            List<OpcData> result = session.read("Objects.CTT.Scalar.Scalar_Instructions").blockingGet();
            for(var dt:result) {
                System.out.println( dt.getValue());
            }
            
            
            
        }
```

[image]

[image]

I'm testing with opc server reference implementation. But I'm not able to reference the variable and I get an Exception

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
at java.base/java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:141)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
```

What is the correct way to point to a node in the OPC-UA tree?

Comment: Are you married to using this library? It has not been updated in some time and its OPC UA implementation is based on an outdated version of Eclipse Milo. You may find it easier to use Milo directly if that is an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I found is:

```
List<OpcData> result = session.read("ns=2;s=Scalar_Instructions").blockingGet();
```

using nodeId.
I hope that this can help somebody.